# Atheist getting islamic marriage ceremony for the sake of tradition by parents?

Tags: quran, nikah, sunnah

Assalamuailakum,

Is this sinful? My parents want to do an islamic marriage ceremony for my athiest brother (hes 28yo) and his girlfriend. They do not believe in Allah swt but my parents say as muslim themselves it is their duty to get them married islamically. This doesn't make sense to me as I feel like it is disrespecting the Islamic marriage tradition. The two people doing it need to have faith in Allah swt to be able for it to mean anything, they would have to convert to Islam right? Otherwise its just an act and its better for them to just get a civil marriage done in the eyes of the Law. Am I correct or are my parents allowed to make them do a "pretend" Islamic marriage ceremony for traditions sake?
They also say doing the Islamic ceremony even if he and his girlfriend do not have faith is a good thing because he might come back to faith through it? And therefore they are doing their duty as Muslims.
My brother being an atheist doesn't care either way about the religious aspect and will just do it because it means nothing to him and he mostly just wants the traditional wedding experience.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. First of all what do you mean by Islamic marriage ceremony? In Islam there are rulings for a valid marriage, but no specific ceremony. The rulings for a valid marriage apply on Muslim (to be) spouses however the bride could be from upon the people of book.

Comment: "The bride and groom demonstrate their free will by repeating the word qabul ("I accept," in Arabic) three times. Then the couple and two male witnesses sign the contract, making the marriage legal according to civil and religious law. Vows/blessings:
The officiant may additional religious ceremony following the nikah, which usually includes a recitation of the Fatihah—the first chapter of the Quran—and durud (blessings). Most Muslim couples do not recite vows; rather, they listen as their officiant speaks about the meaning of marriage and their responsibilities to each other and Allah."

Comment: Having an imam officiate it and signing a nikkah? This would be an Islamic marriage ceremony no? And would 2 atheists be okay to take part in it?

Comment: I thought this is the general understanding of a Muslim marriage ceremony? : https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zcjqrwx/revision/6#:~:text=A%20Muslim%20wedding%20ceremony%20is,of%20witnesses%20for%20both%20partners.

Comment: hm... "The bride does not have to be present as long as she sends two witnesses to the drawn-up agreement." who said that? Is this agreed upon? What is their evidences? Many other rules declared in this text are not agreed upon and more essential ones are left out. As stated an imam or any Muslim person can't marry two atheists following the rules of Islam and if somebody lies about their believe he would be regarded as guilty in front of his creator, if your brother is atheist and so is his girlfriend/wife your parents would commit a sin if they married them hiding their "disbelief".

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. That was just the general definitions of Islamic Wedding Ceremony found online. I think the bride not being present is for weddings that are segregrated. Ofcourse it differs from culture to culture, and my brother will still have a cultural wedding. But my main concern was whether holding an Islamic ceremony such as the one described for the sake of tradition would be sinful. JazakAllah Khairun!